# Bivariant probability distributions

Tags: probability

Let $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1, & \ \ -x\le y\le x,\  0\le x \le 1 \\
0, & \ \ \text{else}\end{cases}$

be an absolutely continuous probability density.

I want to compute the Cummulative Distribution Function (CDF) for $X$ and $Y$, meaning the two marginal distribution functions and their respective expectation values.

Let's start with the CDF of $X$:

$\int^x_{-\infty} \int^x_{-x} \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x=x^2$

I am not sure whether to integrate $y$ over $[-x,x]$ or $[-1,1]$ here. My guess would be the latter, because I want a distribution independent of $y$ and therefore "pretend" every value of $y$ has already been adopted.

Secondly, I want to proceed with the expectation value of $Y$. Assume, I have already found the marginal density function of $Y$ and call it $f_Y(y)$. I would then proceed with

$E(Y)=\int^{x}_{-x} y f_Y(y)\mathrm{d}y$ and here again I am not sure whether to integrate over $[-1,1]$ or $[-x,x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's make a drawing of $f_{X,Y}$:

[image]
By definition and because of the support of the common density, we have

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dy=\int_{-x}^x\ dy=2x$$
if $0\le x\le 1.$

Also,

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx=\int_{y}^1\ dx=\begin{cases}1-y&\text{ if }&0\le y\le 1\\
1+y&\text{ if }& -1\le y<0\\
0&\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

As far as the expectations

$$E[X]=\int_0^1 2x^2\ dx=\frac23$$

and

$$E[Y]=\int_{-1}^0 y(1+y)\ dy+\int_0^1y(1-y )\ dy=0.$$

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: Thanks, I will check.

Comment: I solved it myself in the meantime. The answer is the same as yours. I might add, that I looked at the cases $y\le x$ for $y\ge 0$ and $-y\le x$ for a $y < 0$. I then took the intervalls $\int^1_{\max\{y,-y\}}$ in respect with whether $y$ is positive or negative. Also, the lesson I learned today: Always draw graphs. Could have seen this immediately from it. Thanks, for your answer!